# I keep having error on remove filters command

Tags: powerbi, dax

Im trying to have a card that have consistent number showing the average per student.

This is the DAX Measure

Measure1 =
AVERAGE(Student_per_types_of_skills[Total_Skills]),REMOVEFILTERS()

I keep having this error
The syntax for ',' is incorrect. (DAX(AVERAGE(Student_per_types_of_skills[Total_Skills]),REMOVEFILTERS()))).

Would anyone could help me with this? Thank you.

I tried to remove the ) and then add specific column too but it doesnt seem to move formward.

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter that without using CALCULATE(), because CALCULATE is the function that allows/enables you to change the filter context of a measure. Instead of this:

```
= AVERAGE(Student_per_types_of_skills[Total_Skills])
```

You need something like this:
CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Student_per_types_of_skills[Total_Skills]),REMOVEFILTERS('Skills'[SkillName]))

If you have a card with a measure on it, and you don't filter your report by clicking on anything (like slicers), you'll get the total for the whole table. If you add that same measure to a matrix, and add a column from a related table, each total will be filtered by the value in the column. If you use REMOVEFILTERS() you can remove a single column from the filter context or an entire table.

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem with that card visual.